# Kubernetes cluster does not get external IP

Tags: kubernetes, service, kubernetes-nodeport

I have created NodePort type service but I never get External IP for my nodes.
Then I am trying to curl using Internal IP but it never works.
[image]

Comment: Hi. Have you tried `curl <HOST_IP>:30346`, whereas `HOST_IP` is the ip address of the host running your cluster?

Comment: Please add the result of `kubectl get svc`